# Como usar o NPM e o Yarn no ASP.Net Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, npm, yarn

Estou com dificuldade em utilizar o Yarn/NPM no ASP.Net Core.

Estou instalando pacotes da seguinte maneira: (Exemplo instalando o JQuery)

**Yarn:** `yarn add jquery`
**NPM:** `npm install jquery`

Ocorre tudo normalmente, o problema é que os arquivos vão para a pasta `node_modules`, enquanto que no ASP.Net Core é "preciso" que os arquivos estejam na `wwwroot`.

Eu adoraria utilizar o **Bower**, já que tem como definir o diretórios das instalações, porém ele não está funcionando e está recomendando o uso do **Yarn**.

Então como eu conseguiria instalar os pacotes a modo de utilizar no ASP.Net Core?

> Se possível, eu gostaria que os arquivos fossem instalados na `wwwroot/lib`.
>
> Eu pesquisei, porém só encontrei algumas coisas em inglês, mas eu sou horrível em inglês e os tradutores dos navegadores não parecem ser tão melhores assim, fica tudo confuso.

Comment: Vinicius, fazer o setup do npm ou yarn eh facil mas pra copiar pro wwwroot vc tem q usar algo como webpack

Comment: @FabriDamazio Utilizei o Gulp pra retornar isso, mas vou ver sobre o WebPack, talvez ele tenha uma forma melhor de se fazer isso. Muito obrigado :D

Comment: @ViníciusLima alguma novidade?

Answer (score 2):

Para isso, é possível usar a flag [`--modules-folder`](https://yarnpkg.com/pt-BR/docs/cli/install#toc-yarn-install-modules-folder):

> **`yarn install --modules-folder <caminho>`**
>
> Especifica um local alternativo para o diretório `node_modules`, ao invés do padrão `./ node_modules`.

Então no seu caso, você poderia instalar o `jquery` usando o seguinte comando:

`$ yarn add jquery --modules-folder wwwroot/lib`

Aí, sua estrutura de pastas deve ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
pasta_raiz
├── package.json
├── wwwroot
│   └── lib
│       └── jquery
│           └── ...arquivos do jquery
└── yarn.lock
```

Porém, à medida que você for instalando mais e mais pacotes do npm, pode ficar um pouco cansativo ficar digitando essa flag com o caminho *toda vez*.

Pra "automatizar" a digitação dessa flag (e de qualquer outra que você precisar usar globalmente no seu projeto), você pode adicionar um arquivo [.yarnrc](https://yarnpkg.com/pt-BR/docs/yarnrc#toc-cli-arguments) na pasta raiz do seu projeto com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
--modules-folder wwwroot/lib
```

Depois disso, basta usar normalmente os comandos `yarn`, `yarn install` ou `yarn add <pacote>` e os módulos já serão salvos automaticamente na pasta `./wwwroot/lib` do seu projeto.

---

A propósito, a [documentação do Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/pt-BR/docs) já está 100% traduzida para português brasileiro, agora ficando mais fácil entender e aprender sobre o Yarn \o/